# Publish rate higher than subscriber rate

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If the publisher rate is set higher than the subscriber rate, will the message rate of the publisher slow down to match the subscriber rate?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/415300/publish-rate-higher-than-subscriber-rate/) by [JoshE](https://answers.ros.org/users/148621/joshe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2023-05-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No, it won't. You'll just end up dropping messages at the subscriber.

If you write another subscriber which runs at a faster rate, it'll receive most/all messages (depending on ROS1/ROS2, and QoS settings)

---

Originally posted by [Gaurav Gupta](https://answers.ros.org/users/72874/gaurav-gupta/) with karma: 276 on 2023-05-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2